# Custom logging handler in Redhar JBoss EAP / BPM Suite 6.4.0

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, business-process-management, redhat-bpm

I would like to provide custom logging handler implementation for Redhat JBoss EAP / BPM Suite 6.4.0. I have my own customized logging mechanism based on log4j and the requirement is to publish all log messages to kafka system instead of file system.

Please suggest.

Thanks.
Aniket

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send all the logging information, you should develop a custom handler (`java.util.logging.Handler`) and add it to root logger (EAP configuration).

If you want to send more BPM specific information you should implement a **Process Event Listener**: look a this 
[example implementation](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-core/src/main/java/org/drools/core/event/DebugProcessEventListener.java).
Then you have to register it the event listener in the `kie-deployment-descriptor.xml`.